# my question is about strange behaviour in a juniper srx 340.. that is not a consumer device

Tags: discussion, moderators

regarding question [add 2nd ip on linux box, juniper refuse to add to ARP](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45393/add-2nd-ip-on-linux-box-juniper-refuse-to-add-to-arp)

all other "consumer" servers have NO problem with the new ip addresses, but clearly my juniper SRX has a problem with this.. this is the right forum for that question I think... please let know how this is a "consumer" question ?

Comment: you are very quick to put questions on hold... but not very quick to tell me why... that is not very good form I think.

Comment: I explained exactly why at the same time I put it on hold.

Comment: so, no discussion needed then, GOD has spoken :-) thanks for you help

Comment: No, the community makes the decision, and Meta is the place for that discussion. It may be that the community decides that your question should be on-topic.

Comment: it says in the help files that I can re-word the question  to make it fit better, but with no input from you guys, how can I improve it?

Comment: well, it seems like it is only you and me here today.. so I will try to ask other comunities, where they would like to help, not just close stuff as off topic and not give any more hints than you do..

Answer (score 1):

The question is not about a host configuration, but why the SRX won't learn a MAC for the secondary address(es). Get past the word *linux*, already.